# If $H$ is an incomplete inner product space there is some closed subspace $H_0$ such that $H_0 \oplus H_0^{\bot} \neq H$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

I am pretty much stucked at this exercise. I have seen a couple of examples of it, but now I need to show that this is true in general.

I know it suffices to find some element $y \in H$ such that its distance with $H_0$ is not attained.
To define a closed subspace in such an abstract space I have considered taking the kernel of some continuous linear functional, maybe the inner product itself.

Now, we should definetively take some Cauchy sequence $\{ x_i \}$ that converges to some $x$ which is not in $H$ and use it maybe to show that the distance of some $y$ with $H_0$ is not attained.

Could someone please help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Let $\hat H$ be the completion of $H$ and $H\ni x_n\to x\in\hat H\setminus H$. I guess $H_0:=x^\perp\cap H$ will work.

Comment: How do you know $H_0$ is closed in $H$? And it is not that clear to me what is $H_0^{\bot}$ in this case. This is since there are two "types" of $\bot$, the one we use in the completion and the one we use in $H$.

Comment: Well, $x^\perp$ only makes sense in $\hat H$ as $x\notin H$, and it's closed in $\hat H$, so $H_0$ is closed in $H$. What I'm uncertain about is that $H_0^\perp$ in $H$ is indeed $\{0\}$.